# showing data from database using forms.py in django

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
    db_table=u'Author'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%d %s %s %s %d" % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email,self.age)



class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Book'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.pk, self.book_name, self.publisher_name)
```

can you please tell me how to write a forms.py and views.py for this model to display the data from database.

my forms.py is

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['author_id','first_name','last_name','email','age']

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields=['book_id','book_name','publisher_name','author_id']
```

So i writen the forms.py in this way it is writen for models field.So please tell me that the form what i given is correct,if not please tell me how to write a forms.py and views.py for displaying the data from database from two tables.

my views.py is

```
def index(request): 
    book = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am not able to show all the data from database.please help me with this.If any problem with my views.py content guide me how to write views.py

my index.html is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>   
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding='8' cellspacing='10'>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="10"><a href="/addbook/">Add Book</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Book Id</>
    <th>Book name</th>
    <th>Publication name</th>
    <th>Author Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>E Mail</th>
    <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for book in books %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ book.book_id }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.book_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.publisher_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.author_id }}</td>    
       <td>{{ book.author.first_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.author.last_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.author.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.author.age }}</td>
       <td><a href="/editbook/{{ book.book_id}}">Edit</a></td>
       <td><a href="/deletebook/{{ book.book_id}}">Delete</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you want to show all the data in your models?

Comment: So, if you are not trying to edit some date or add some things to your models you don't need to use forms. You can create a view to do this or use a generic view. Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list

Comment: ya but i am trying this using forms.py sir,please tel me how to move

Comment: can any one please tell me how to write views.py for the above snippets.Please see the views.py which i writen is correct

Comment: how is your index.html?

Comment: sir.i had updated the index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your views.py:

```
from models import Book
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request): 
   books = Book.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('index.html', 
       locals(),
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: yes sir,it is working.here we are not using forms to display the answer.Is it possible to do the same using forms.py if possible please tell me how to do..Thanks

Comment: actually, when you create a form in django is to create or edit some data. To show your models you may use views.py, ok? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your models and forms look correct off hand.  Please see [part 4 of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/) for help writing views to connect them.

Comment: can you please tell me how to write a views.py to display the data from  database

Comment: ya but i am trying this using forms.py sir,please tel me how to move

Comment: If you're using the `UpdateView` generic view, but want to have a custom form, you can specify the `form_class` on the view.  See this example: https://gist.github.com/flaviamissi/1275204